# do i need to translate information coming from wordpress like author name the post title, post content etc making a translation ready wp theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i am developing a wordpress theme for themeforest and i want to ask that is it my responsiblity to translate the information coming from wordpress like the the post title, post content or the author name etc as making a translation ready theme or does wordpress handles this on its own. i don't want my theme to be soft rejected from themeforest because i didn't translated the information coming from wordpress. as its there requirement to translate all of your strings if making a translation ready theme. also obviously i am using wordpress function to get that information i.e post title, post content or the author name etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the content returned by the functions get_the_title() or the_content() are proper to the content of the site, this content should not be translated by the theme, the website administrator should provide the different languages of its content.

To translate the theme you can use the tool: [POEDIT](https://poedit.net/)
following the recommendations given in the [WordPress Handbook Internationalization](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/internationalization/)